# Multiple values auto completed on AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I have an autoComplete text view in which i am asking the user to enter names.

The user might want to insert few names.

How can i give him the option to insert few names whilw every insertion acoompanied by a autocomplete suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a new name, you could store it to some kind of data structure or even database, and the next time the autocomplete is used then it is populated by the names + the new name added to the database or data structure.

The following code may be a rough guide for you

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    names = db.getUniqueExercises(); //Database query 

    AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoNames);

    myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, names)); //Add the names to the autoComplete
```